# Como descobrir a versão do meu C/C++ no sistema operacional Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

Gostaria de aprender a descobrir a versão do meu `C/C++` no sistema operacional `Linux`.

Como eu poderia fazer isso através do `Terminal`?

Comment: Voce quer saber a versao do seu compilador de C, a versao do seu compilador de C++, a versao da libc instalada no seu computador ou a versao da libstdc++ instalada no seu computador? Sao 4 coisas distintas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para saber a versao do seu compilador C, este comando deve funcionar:

```
gcc --version
```

ou

```
gcc -v
```

Basta digitar em um terminal do Linux.

Note que o compilador de C, o compilador de C++, a libc e a libstdc++ sao coisas distintas entre si.

Answer (score 0):

Para Windows (via linha de comando) e Linux (via terminal):

```
gcc --version  // 
g++ --version
make --version 
gdb --version
```

Obs: se preferir limpar a tela entre um comando e outro:

```
cls // CDM - Windows

clear // Terminal - Linux
Ctrl + L // Terminal - Linux. Mas esse comando apenas insere espaços ou quebras de linha.
         // Se pressionar Direcional Up ⬆ verá o os comandos e resultados anteriores por lá.
         // Esse comando não está disponível no CDM. Logo, funciona apenas no Terminal.
```